# Change default language for app listing in iTunes Connect

Tags: app-store-connect

My developer has added a new app in iTunes Connect for me, but the default language is "UK English". I've now also added the generic "English".

I now want to delete "UK English", but I can't because it's the default. I can only delete the generic English. **How do I change which language is the default?**

Comment: I think it's a bit inaccurate to say that "English" is "generic". In App Store, "English" means "US English". Formerly, there was a convenient table in the iTC doc., explaining which stores that were using which languages. There, one could see that all countries that did not have their native language defined in iTunes, were actually using "UK English", not "English". "English" was only used in the US. Even if that table is now gone, I guess that App Store is still using "UK English" for unsupported languages. So from this point of view, I think "UK English" is more generic than "English".

Answer (score 87):

According to [App Store Docs](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/deve6f78a8e2?sub=devb34f436a9) :

1. open **[Appstore Connect](https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/)** and sign in to your account
2. Open `My Apps`
3. Choose the app you want to edit its **Primary Language**
4. Choose the latest version you have (Must be `Prepare for Submission` or `Waiting for Review`)
5. Add the second language (the one which you want to be the primary)

[image]

6. Select the new language
7. In Screenshots **Uncheck** `Use English (U.S.)` from each device screenshots
8. Click `Save`

> if your app is already **available on app store** you will need to upload
>   your screenshots and fill all fields for this language and submit this
>   version **to review**, then finish the next steps on another update **after approval** of this version

9. Now you can set the primary language from `App information --> Primary language`

[image]

10. Click `Save`
11. Now you can delete the language which you don't need from the same option where you added the second language

Comment: I couldn't find the screen, it opens the About the App modal with no editing capabilities.

Comment: @BrunoMachado-vargero make sure you've added a second language before you open `About This App` , else you won't be able to edit **Primary Language** .. (check step 4)

Comment: The app statute should not be `Ready for Sale`.. if it, it can't be edited

Comment: Perhaps you forgot to save after you added the second language. This happens to me too.

Comment: I've got error "you must choose primary language" on step 7. But language deleted without problems from page "1.0 Prepare for Submission".

Comment: "You must have at least two localized languages" why? can you show a documentation about this?

Comment: I am not able to change primary language of the app in new version. Primary Language Option under App Information on iTunes is not actionable there. Can anyone have any idea?

Comment: @Tejinder Check out step 4 which will be available only if you have a new version with status (Prepare for Submission)

Comment: When option to select primary language is not actionable, you need to remove current build, save, go back to App Information, select primary language, go back to Prepare for Submission, add the same build again. Done.

Answer (score 30):

***EDIT: Since September 2014 this answer out-of-date as the iTunes Connect interface has changed***

I discovered that there is a way to change the default language after all:

1. in iTunes Connect, go to **Manage your apps**
2. Click the relevant app
3. Click the **Edit** link in the heading "App Information"
4. The dropdown **Default language** contains all the languages that have been added. Pick any one (I chose the generic "English" mentioned in the question), then save.
5. Click the button **View Details** in the second section.
6. Generic "English" is now default. In **Choose Another Language:** pick the "UK English".
7. In the heading **Metadata and Uploads** there's now a **Delete** button.

That's it!

Comment: I hung on step number 5. This answer is right - http://stackoverflow.com/a/11052389/1263701

Comment: Notice that your new app version (with the added language) need to be published and "Ready for Sale" before it's possible to change the default language as explained above. It's not even visible in the drop-down in step 4 before it's ready.

Comment: But the new added language which is not in the drop-down list of step 4, cannot be set as the default language by this method.

Answer (score 2):

After September 2015 iTunes Connect update things have changed a little bit so the right steps (as of today) are:

1. Add the desired language in App Store → App Information → Localizable Information
2. Click Save
3. Now the Primary Language section have become a dropdown from which you can choose the desired language

BTW, documentation is updated so you can find relevant info [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/DisplayInMoreLanguages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH28-SW7).

Hope this helps.

Comment: But it is only work for those app have not published. It the app has not been published at least one time. The Primary Language section have now become a dropdown to choose

Comment: You can add new languages only if the app status is editable ([About App Statuses](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ChangingAppStatus.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH30-SW23)). Otherwise you can change primary language only if you already have languages to choose from.

Answer (score 2):

currently Apple documentation about this is here:

https://developer.apple.com/help/app-store-connect/manage-app-information/localize-app-store-information

look for "Change the primary language".

basically, add a new localization from the "App Store" section, then switch the primary language in "App Information", then optionally delete the previous primary language from "App Store" section if needed