# Change application default description language

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I'm submitting a new version of my app into app store.

Is there a way to change the default application language in iTunesConnect ?

Let say I have a French as a default description language and I need to change the ***default*** to English. How do I do that ?

Comment: Were you able to work it out?

Comment: no, see my comment on your answer

Comment: It's possible, see my comment in the answer below.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your App must be in the "Ready for Sale" state. Then,

1. Go to your list of apps
2. Open the desired app
3. Click "Edit" on "App Information"
4. Set the Default Language and save

Comment: The combobox displays only one language in App Information, i.e. only French in my case.

Comment: That probably means that is the only language you have entered for your app in iTunes Connect. I just checked on one of my apps that only has one language, and indeed, in that case, I only see that option on the Default Language combo box. On the other hand, on one of my apps with multiple iTunes languages, I'm able to see all of them on the combo box.

Comment: I've submitted and English localization description for the next update. I guess I'll be able to see that upon update publication. Then the combobox will show English also I guess.

Comment: We had the exact same problem, we published our first version in Swedish (which is set as default language). Then later we added English and wanted it to be the default language. It wasn't possible to change this until the app was published to App Store with the status "Ready for Sale". When this status changed English was selectable in the drop-down in step 4 above.